# group by date aggregate function in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I'm getting an error running this query

```
SELECT date(updated_at), count(updated_at) as total_count 
FROM "persons"
WHERE ("persons"."updated_at" BETWEEN '2012-10-17 00:00:00.000000' AND '2012-11-07     12:25:04.082224') 
GROUP BY date(updated_at)
ORDER BY persons.updated_at DESC
```

I get the error ERROR:  column "persons.updated_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an   aggregate function LINE 5: ORDER BY persons.updated_at DESC

This works if I remove the date( function from the group by call, however I'm using the date function because i want to group by date,  not datetime

any ideas

Answer (score 45, accepted):

At the moment it is unclear what you want Postgres to return. You say it should order by `persons.updated_at` but you do not retrieve that field from the database.

I think, what you want to do is:

```
SELECT date(updated_at), count(updated_at) as total_count 
FROM "persons"
WHERE ("persons"."updated_at" BETWEEN '2012-10-17 00:00:00.000000' AND '2012-11-07     12:25:04.082224') 
GROUP BY date(updated_at)
ORDER BY count(updated_at) DESC -- this line changed!
```

Now you are explicitly telling the DB to sort by the resulting value from the COUNT-aggregate. You could also use: `ORDER BY 2 DESC`, effectively telling the database to sort by the second column in the resultset. However I highly prefer explicitly stating the column for clarity.

**Note** that I'm currently unable to test this query, but I do think this should work.

Answer (score 10):

the problem is that, because you are grouping by `date(updated_at)`, the value for `updated_at` may not be unique, different values of `updated_at` can return the same value for `date(updated_at)`.  You need to tell the database *which* of the possible values it should use, or alternately use the value returned by the group by, probably one of

```
SELECT date(updated_at) FROM persons GROUP BY date(updated_at)
ORDER BY date(updated_at)
```

or

```
SELECT date(updated_at) FROM persons GROUP BY date(updated_at)
ORDER BY min(updated_at)
```

Comment: `min()`in the `ORDER BY` saved my day!