# SQL GROUP BY but treat two values as one

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a transaction table like this

```
id | amount | transaction_date | status
---+--------+------------------+-------
 1 |   20   |   2021-01-01     |   1
 2 |   30   |   2021-01-01     |   2
 3 |   10   |   2021-01-01     |   3
 4 |   50   |   2021-01-01     |   1
```

I want to query the transactions to be grouped by transaction date and status. But for particular status, I want them to be counted or treated as 1 status. for example if I query the data like this

```
select status, sum(amount), transaction_date
from transactions
group by status, transaction_date
```

I will get this result

```
status | amount | transaction_date
-------+--------+-----------------
   1   |   70   |    2021-01-01   
   2   |   30   |    2021-01-01   
   3   |   10   |    2021-01-01
```

my questions is how do I group status 2 and 3 as the same status, let's say as some alias 'complete', how do I get this result:

```
  status  | amount | transaction_date
----------+--------+-----------------
'pending' |   70   |    2021-01-01    
'complete'|   40   |    2021-01-01
```

or is this impossible to query in Postgresql?

Comment: may this link help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270172/group-by-date-aggregate-function-in-postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6b2d0eb791af5591bf9edfef1268efd3)

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 'pending' ELSE 'complete' END as status,   -- 1
    SUM(amount) as amount,
    transaction_date
FROM transactions
GROUP BY 1, transaction_date                                             -- 2
```

1. You can use the `CASE` clause to create the `pending` status for `1` and `complete` for `2` and `3`. Of course you need to adapt this to your actual requirements, maybe `CASE WHEN status IN (2,3) THEN ... ELSE..` or add a second `WHEN` branch or whatever...
2. Then you can reference this `CASE` clause column in the `GROUP BY`

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply and it's working as I want it to be. But I have a question about the "GROUP BY 1" part. When I change the group by 1 to "GROUP BY status", because in SELECT clause they're aliased to "status", it doesn't give me the same result. Why is it has to be GROUP BY 1? what does 1 mean here?

Comment: If you grouped by "status", the query would take the old status column, not the new one. That's the different result. The 1 references the new column to avoid a second CASE clause in the GROUP BY (it points to the first column, the new status). However, you can reference the new column name as well, but than it must be different from the old one, like "new_status" or so: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=178cce0b790d7b36498d911852258f49

Answer (score 0):

What about making a new variable called status_text (pending/complete)?

case
when status in (2,3) then 'complete' end as "status_text"
else 'pending'

You can make this in a inner select and group by "status_text" summing amount?

Regards,

Christian

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a reference table for the statuses.  Absent that, you can create one in the query:

```
select v.status_type, sum(tr.amount), t.transaction_date
from transactions t join
     (values (1, 'pending'), (2, 'complete'), (3, 'complete')
     ) v(status, status_type)
     using (status)
group by v.status, t.transaction_date;
```

However, this logic should be stored in a table (called, say, `statuses` or `dim_status` or `status_reference` or whatever).

Why?  You don't want to repeat this logic in different queries at different points of time.  That will lead to bugs.  Further, coding the lookup in individual query makes it dangerous to add new status.  Plus, you might have different features of the status that you could add as additional columns in a reference table.